# Overwriting Json File with new Json Data

Tags: php, json

So I have this json file (json.json) stored on a server, I would like to overwrite it with new json Data ('refresh_token' object to be exact) everytime I call on this php class:

```
    $file = file_get_contents('/var/json.json');
    $json = json_decode($file);
    **$REFRESH_TOKEN** = $json->refresh_token;

    $json = file_get_contents("https://xxxxxxxxxxx&refresh_token=**$REFRESH_TOKEN**");
    $obj = json_decode($json, true);
    $AccessToken = $obj->access_token;
    $RefreshToken = $obj->refresh_token;
    **file_put_contents('/var/json.json', json_encode($RefreshToken));**
```

The json file looks like this:

```
     {"token_type":"bearer",
    "expires_in":3600,
    "scope":"xxxxxxx",
    "access_token":"xxxx",
    **"refresh_token":"xxxxx",**
    "user_id":"xxxxxx"}
```

I repeatedly get the error: `Trying to get property of non-object in` whenever I call the class for a second time. I looked inside the json file after the first call and realized that it did not contain anything. This indicates that the `file_put_contents('/var/json.json', json_encode($RefreshToken))` did not work.

Can anyone give me a hint as to what i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, it is not obvious what you are trying to do. I guess it is the following:

- fetch json object from file
- modify refresh token
- write json object back to file

This would work as follows:

```
$REFRESHTOKEN = $_GET['REFRESH_TOKEN']; // Calculate refresh token
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('/var/json.json')); // fetch json object from file
$json->refresh_token = $REFRESHTOKEN // modify refresh token
file_put_contents('/var/json.json', json_encode($json)); // write json object back to file
```

What you are doing is writing ONLY the refresh token into the file, not the whole object. This is why on the second attempt, the object is not there...

Comment: Yes, that's what I trying to do. Fetch the refresh_token from the json file, modify it, and then overwrite the old refresh_token with the new one back into the json file. What does the first line in your code accomplish?

Comment: It takes the REFRESH TOKEN from somewhere, because I did not understand where you wanted to take it from in your code.

Comment: Solved! @Alexander, You were right about writing only the refresh_token into the json file. I put the whole bunch of json objects as parameters in the file_put_contents method and it worked like chamr. I still dont understand why i wouldnt just only encode the refresh_token into the json file.

Comment: Because in `json_encode($RefreshToken)`, the variable ONLY contains the token.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have permission to write on the file. Change file permission to 777.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the 2nd parameter of `json_decode` to `true` you get an associative array instead of an object.

Documentation for `json_decode`: http://php.net//manual/en/function.json-decode.php